# want to see image in preview using html tag and getting error in visual studio code

Tags: html, anchor

i put the code like this to see the picture in preview in visual studio code :

```
<a href="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35fb99d76447c4eb1f28/master/pass/phonepicutres-TA.jpg"</a>
```

and received the error like this:

> Previewing a file that is not a child of the server root. To see fully
> correct relative file links, please open a workspace at the project
> root or consider changing your server root settings for Live Preview.

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
<a href="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35fb99d76447c4eb1f28/master/pass/phonepicutres-TA.jpg"</a>
```

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket (>) in your anchor element. Could that be it? Also, why are you using an anchor element to display an image?

Answer (score -1):

It might be your extension problem. So Press *(Ctrl + P)* in **VS Code** and paste below command. it would be fixed.

`ext install kisstkondoros.vscode-gutter-preview`

Answer (score -1):

Because maybe you are using an anchor  tag without specifying an  tag to actually show the image. The error message you're receiving might be related to how the preview functionality in Visual Studio Code is interpreting your code.

```
<img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35fb99d76447c4eb1f28/master/pass/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="Description of the image">
```